# Remove job from quartz-jobs.xml file

Tags: c#, xml, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I have been using the `DeleteJob()` method to remove a job that has expired from my scheduler. But I also want that job and its associated triggers to be removed from the `quartz-jobs.xml` file. How can I make that happen?

Comment: DeleteJob() does exactly that according to the source code.

Comment: @CircularReference yes but I cannot see that happening for some reason.

Comment: are you using the correct JobKey? DeleteJob() returns bool if the job was found and deleted.

Comment: @CircularReference it returns false. But I can see my job key. I have 3 jobs and all of them should be deleted. What could be the problem?

Comment: @Pedram Did you find a way to update the xml file? I have a similar issue. Or is it that the xml file is read-only?

Comment: @SmartDev I consulted some Quartz.Net experts on this issue. And I got the answer. Editing the xml file is actually not recommended at all. Instead I tried getting my Scheduler instance in the program and add or remove jobs from it. This way I wouldn't have to worry about expired jobs because Quartz.Net automatically removes them. And now I have set up an `AdoJobStore` and this way my scheduler information will not be lost. Things are looking much better now and I got rid of the `xml` file headache.